# jquery ajax() data, can only pass parameters as string

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
function db_query(id)
{
    $.ajax({   
        type: "GET",
        url: "db_handler.php",          
        data: { row_id:id, foo: "bar" },
        dataType: "html",  
        success: function(response){                   
                  // ...
        }
    });   
}
```

Hey guys, what am I doing wrong here?

In my php script I receive the variables passed as strings, but I'm unable to read them when they are passed as variables.

$_GET output:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => bar
)
```

Comment: It should work. What is the value of `id`?

Comment: How are you calling `db_query()`?  What is `id`?

Comment: id is int(10)  db_query() is bound to a click event

Comment: How is `db_query()` bound to the event?  Are you sure `id` is an int and not something else?  What do you see if you do `console.log(int, typeof int);` at the top of `db_query()`?

Comment: It shouldn't matter what type `int` is, jQuery will convert it to a string when it puts it into the URL parameters. Are you sure the AJAX call is coming from this function?

Comment: Is the request leaving the browser with the correct params?

Comment: suddenly it started working, i guess somehow I was caching old data. Thank you all.